# List of complex objects to list of named tuples

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

Given a `List<ComplexObject>`, how can I create a new list of named tuples? So for every `ComplexObject` in the original list, create a new tuple with certain values from the `ComplexObject`?

```
public class ComplexObject 
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
    // More properties that are irrelevant for the purpose of this question...
}
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
List<ComplexObject> complexObjects = new List<ComplexObject>
{
    new ComplexObject { SomeString = "SomeString01", SomeInt = 1, SomeBool = true },
    new ComplexObject { SomeString = "SomeString02", SomeInt = 2, SomeBool = false },
    new ComplexObject { SomeString = "SomeString03", SomeInt = 3, SomeBool = true },
};

List<(string SomeString, int SomeInt, bool SomeBool)> complexTuples 
    = complexObjects.SelectMany(obj => (obj.SomeString, obj.SomeInt, obj.SomeBool));
```

However this results in an error:

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany(IEnumerable, Func>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, with just two problems:

- You need to use `Select` rather than `SelectMany`, are you're just performing a 1:1 transform
- You need a call to `ToList` to get a `List<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`:

```cs
List<(string SomeString, int SomeInt, bool SomeBool)> complexTuples =
    complexObjects.Select(obj => (obj.SomeString, obj.SomeInt, obj.SomeBool)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, method `SelectMany` flattens the collection of collections to a single collection and since it's not the case here you don't need to use this function.

So instead we will use `.Select`. Don't forget that `.Select` returns `IEnumerable<T>` and if we try to assign it to `List<T>` it will fail.

You could change your code to:

```
List<(string SomeString, int SomeInt, bool SomeBool)> complexTuples
                = complexObjects.Select(obj => (obj.SomeString, obj.SomeInt, obj.SomeBool)).ToList();
```

And it works as expected now.